# How to create an alias for a function using Unicode characters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators

I want to create Unicode aliases for some standard functions in the Haskell library. Here was my attempt.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import qualified Data.List as List
import qualified Data.Map  as Map
import qualified Data.Set  as Set


-- Convenient aliases for common operations via Unicode symbols.
∩ = Set.intersection
∪ = Set.union
⊆ = Set.isSubsetOf
⊊ = Set.isProperSubsetOf
∈ = Set.member 

main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error

```
[~/Desktop]$ ghc --make test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:10:1: parse error on input ‘∩’
[~/Desktop]$
```

I want to use these unicode symbols as infix operators, and hopefully without the backticks. How does one do this?

Comment: [There's a library for this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-unicode-symbols-0.3.1.1/docs/Data-Set-Unicode.html) ;)

Comment: @ MarLinn Wow! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to surround your new functions with parantheses when you declare them:

```
(∩) = Set.intersection
```

Note that you also need to remove capital letters from the function you import from `Data.Set`, because `Set.Intersection` is seen as a data constructor and not as a function (and doesn't exist in fact).

Answer (score 6):

Just like when defining any other infix operator point-free, you need to wrap the operator in parentheses at its point of definition:

```
(∩) = Set.intersection
(∪) = Set.union
(⊆) = Set.isSubsetOf
(⊊) = Set.isProperSubsetOf
(∈) = Set.member
```

Because these characters are all classified as symbols, they are treated as infix operators, with or without `UnicodeSyntax` (which simply allows certain unicode characters in places reserved as language syntax, such as `::`).

Comment: As the other answer indicates, the capitalization is also wrong.